# Arithmetic question with distance speed and time

Tags: arithmetic

If I have a time of departure with is 10:35 and I have an arrival time of 12:55 and the distance 36km how do I calculate average speed?
I get the formula of distance speed and time but it says the answer is 15 3/7 km/hr and I’m really confused on how it is.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Avg speed = total distance / total time.  Have you computed these?

Comment: What is the elapsed time in hours from $10$:$35$ to $12$:$55$?

Comment: Tried finding the differences of the times which got me 02:20 and I had to covert it to 2 1/3 hours and then I know I have to divide 36 by something but that’s as far as I got really

Comment: Just divide it by that and you get the answer.

Comment: Yes I have tried computing that formula some how

Comment: That does not get me 15 3/7 as the answer though?

Comment: $2 \frac{1}{3} = \frac{7}{3}$ and $\frac{36}{\frac{7}{3}} = \frac{36\cdot 3}{7} = \frac{108}{7} = 15\frac{3}{7}$.

Comment: I need a solution to this answer that is what I don’t get. I get so far and then I miss a step which doesn’t get me the answer which is 15 3/7

Comment: Wait how do you get 7/3 sorry if I’m asking stupid questions

Comment: 2+1/3 = 6/3+1/3=7/3.

Comment: You can rewrite is as an improper fraction. $2$ is the same as $\frac{6}{3}$ so $2\frac{1}{3}$ is the same as $\frac{6+1}{3} = \frac{7}{3}$.

Comment: Okay I got thank you so much guys you’re all life savers!!

Comment: What if it doesn’t say the distance travelled or average speed and it’s just the time of departure= 12:15 and time of arrival=14:45 how do you calculate distance travelled?

Answer (score 0):

Once you calculated 2 1/3 hours, you can figure out what to do next with units. The answer is speed, which has units (distance)/(time). So you divide the distance (36 km) by the time (2 1/3 hours) to get 15 3/7 km/hr.